# Calendar/datepicker with blocked dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am currently developing an order system where the user can select which day they would like their order to be delivered.

I need to have a page where a calendar/datepicker is visible (not activated by popup) at all times and has all past dates, todays date and 3 days into the future blocked out. The user can then select from the dates available which is then submitted to the client.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you found out so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

The description says this:
"Set the beginning and end dates as actual dates (new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26)), **as a numeric offset from today (-20)**, or as a string of periods and units ('+1M +10D')"

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it to work. Just need to get the date picker to submit the value now :)

Comment: I will do. Do you know how I submit the value from the datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

> http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#options

See  `minDate` and `maxDate`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to always display the calendar:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

It looks like the blackout-date feature can be achieved through the beforeShowDay callback, or by simply setting the calendar min/max.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/custom-callback-to-disable-specific-dates-in-datepicker

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({..., beforeShowDay: allowedDates});

function allowedDates(date) {
      for (var i = 0; i < jsForbiddenDatesArray.length; i++) {
            if (date.getTime() == jsForbiddenDatesArray[i].getTime()) {
                  return [false, ''];
            }
      }
      return $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by two types

1. set mindate and maxdate
2. when you open the datepicker and change month/year it will fire an event `beforeShowDay` with each date on that month and year, and you can check for each date in that function with your date range array or object and return true or false. If false return that date will be deactive and on true that date will be active